# ASP.NET - Programmatic Edit

Tags: asp.net, gridview

How can we programmatically take a GridView-row into Edit-mode using an Edit Command?

Suppose I want to edit the name of the course 'C++'.

How can I do that?

[image]

[Also see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302275/asp-net-editing-a-gridview-row-again)

Comment: JMSA, I would like to politely suggest that you try searching the documentation before posting your questions.  I notice that you ask a lot of questions that are already very richly documented.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx

Comment: Can you see the word 'Programmatically'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the event handler:

```
gridView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
gridView.DataBind();
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.EditIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;//no property named Item
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }

e don't have Item property.