# ASP.NET - working with GridView Programmatically

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am continuing from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301581/asp-net-programmatic-edit).

After much Googling, I have come up with this code to edit cells programmatically:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

using Ice_Web_Portal.BO;

namespace GridView___Test
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = Course.GetCourses();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];

            GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

            GridView1.DataSource = Course.GetCourses();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox txtID = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Controls[0];
            TextBox txtCourseCode = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Controls[0];
            TextBox txtCourseName = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Controls[0];
            TextBox txtCourseTextBookCode = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Controls[0];

            Course item = new Course();
            item.ID = Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text);
            item.CourseCode = txtCourseCode.Text;
            item.CourseName = txtCourseName.Text;
            item.TextBookCode = txtCourseTextBookCode.Text;

            bool success = Course.Update(item);

            labMessage.Text = success.ToString();

            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            GridView1.DataSource = Course.GetCourses();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

But 2 problems are happening.

(1) I need to press command buttons twice to Edit/Update.

(2) Changes in the cell values are not updated in the database. I.e. edited cell values are not committing.

Can anyone give me a solution?

UPDATE: My solution was like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="GridView___Test._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="Small" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">            
        </asp:GridView>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>

namespace GridView___Test
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                CreateGridView();
            }
        }

        private void CreateGridView()
        {
            GridView1.Columns.Clear();

            DataTable dataTable = Book.GetBooksDataSet().Tables[0];

            CommandField cf = new CommandField();
            cf.ShowEditButton = true;

            GridView1.Columns.Add(cf);

            int colCount = 1;
            foreach (DataColumn c in dataTable.Columns)
            {
                BoundField boundField = new BoundField();

                boundField.DataField = c.ColumnName;
                boundField.HeaderText = c.ColumnName;
                //boundField.FooterText = "---";

                if (colCount == 3 || colCount == 5)
                {
                    boundField.ReadOnly = true;
                }

                GridView1.Columns.Add(boundField);
                colCount++;
            }

            GridView1.ShowFooter = true;

            GridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
            GridView1.DataBind();

            GridViewRow footerRow = GridView1.FooterRow;
            Button b = new Button();
            b.Text = "Add New";
            int i = 0;
            footerRow.Cells[i].Controls.Add(b);
            foreach (DataColumn c in dataTable.Columns)
            {
                ++i;
                TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                footerRow.Cells[i].Controls.Add(tb);
            }
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

            if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
            {
                //Takes the GridView to Edit mode.
                GridView1.EditIndex = index;

                GridViewRow selectedRow = ((GridView)e.CommandSource).Rows[index];

                //We can get cell data like this
                string id = selectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
                string isbn = selectedRow.Cells[2].Text;

                //This is necessary to GridView to be showed up.
                CreateGridView();
            }
            else if (e.CommandName == "Update")
            {
                LinkButton updateButton = (LinkButton)e.CommandSource;

                DataControlFieldCell dcfc = (DataControlFieldCell)updateButton.Parent;

                GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)dcfc.Parent;

                //The update...................
                //Update grid-data to database
                UpdateDataInTheDatabase(gvr.Cells[1].Controls);                

                //Grid goes back to normal
                GridView1.EditIndex = -1;

                //This is necessary to GridView to be showed up.
                CreateGridView();
            }
        }

        private void UpdateDataInTheDatabase(ControlCollection cc)
        {
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)cc[0];
            //...
            //...
            //...

            //Call the update persistance code here...
        }

        #region Application Satisfactory Event Handlers
        protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for problem #1,try

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
        GridView1.DataSource = Course.GetCourses();
        GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

for problem #2, we need to check your method `Course.Update(item)` .

Comment: My Update method has no problem I think, coz when i am casting cells to TextBoxes, they are showing me old values always. I.e. edited cell values are not being committed.

Comment: If Update method is not working, may be problem is in your sql procedures or transaction is left open and any sql statement does not execute.
Make sure of that please.

Comment: I have checked it multiple times. Can you understand what I said? When I am typing a new value in the cell using my keyboard, I am not finding that value. I am finding the old value instead. ANd I am finding it before the Update. If the new value is not entering the newly created Course object, how can it be Updated in the DB?

Answer (score 0):

```
//To Add Esit,Update,Cancel in gridview control ..... 
//source 
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" HeaderText="Edit Product Name &amp; Price" />

//c# code
  public void gris()
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from Product_details", con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            Gridview1.DataSource = ds;
            Gridview1.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }
 protected void Gridview1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            Gridview1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            gris();
        }

        protected void Gridview1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
        {
            Gridview1.EditIndex = -1;
            gris();
        }

        protected void Gridview1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            string id = addproduct2.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            string name = ((TextBox)addproduct2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text;//(or)Controls[1]
            string rate = ((TextBox)addproduct2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text;//(or)Controls[1]
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("update Product_details set product_name='" + name + "',Product_rate='" + rate + "',product_unitprice='" + rate + "' where product_id='" + id + "'", con);
            int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (i >= 1)
            {
                Response.Write("Updated");
            }
            con.Close();
            Gridview1.EditIndex = -1;
            gris();

        }
```