# ASP.NET - GridView Programmatic Cell Edit (Help!)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

Can anyone provide me any web link of how to programmatically edit and update a GridView Cell using CommandField and normal CRUD operation (I.e. without using SqlDataSource)?

**My goal is to achieve this by writing only C# code and minimum asp.net scripting.**

You can have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301581/asp-net-programmatic-edit) and [this post also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302275/asp-net-editing-a-gridview-row-again) (my failed requests!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try....

```
    ((Label)grd.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("lblID")).Text = "your new cell text";
```

where Cells[0]= your cell index